# Cannot add network after removing the same one in android

Tags: android

In the below code I have a class for managing Wifi connection with WifiManager. 
My problem is when I remove a network then I cannot add same network until turning off and on my phone's wifi.

```
public class ConnectWifi {

private Context _ctx;
private WifiManager _wifiManager;

public ConnectWifi(Context ctx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
_ctx=ctx;
_wifiManager= (WifiManager) _ctx.getSystemService(_ctx.WIFI_SERVICE);
}

void ConnectToWifi(String _SSID,String _KeyPass){

    //_wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

    //wpa
    int Id=0;


    Id=wificonfig(_SSID, _KeyPass);

    if(Id!=-1)
     _wifiManager.enableNetwork(Id, true);        

}

void myRemoveNetwork(){


    int ID=_wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
    //_wifiManager.disconnect();
    _wifiManager.removeNetwork(ID);
    _wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
        }


int wificonfig(String _SSID,String _KeyPass){
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wc.SSID =String.format("\"%s\"", _SSID); 
    wc.preSharedKey  = String.format("\"%s\"", _KeyPass);

    wc.hiddenSSID = true;
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    int Id = _wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
    return Id;
   }
 }
```

how I can add network after removing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the WifiManager and it sounds like a bug to me. But if you want to remove a network and then add it again, then maybe you really want to disable it and enable it instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I want to remove configuration so user cannot connect to the network without using my app, by disabling network android is going to keep the configuration so the user can connect to the network without using my app.